# Spring-Boot-Admin server fails to register clients from Eureka registry

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-admin

I just created a new Spring-Boot-Admin project from the Initializr, and followed the instructions from here: http://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/2.0.0/

Here is my class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableAdminServer
public class ServiceAdminApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServiceAdminApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Here is my properties file:

```
eureka.instance.leaseRenewalIntervalInSeconds=10
eureka.instance.health-check-url-path=/actuator/health
eureka.client.registryFetchIntervalSeconds=5
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://my.eureka.url:8580/eureka/

management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*  
management.endpoint.health.show-details=ALWAYS
```

I have a working Eureka registry which has a number of Spring-Boot applications registered in it. I know this is working because they are able to find each other and communicate via the Eureka registry.

When I start my new SBA app, I can see it register itself within the Eureka registry, so it is finding Eureka. However, when I open the SBA UI, it is empty, just saying "No applications registered." On my console, I can see the following stack trace over and over.

> java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the
>   software in your host machine     at
>   sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]     at
>   sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:51)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_151]   at
>   sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_151]   at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_151]   at
>   sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_151]   at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel.write(NioChannel.java:134)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioBlockingSelector.write(NioBlockingSelector.java:101)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.write(NioSelectorPool.java:157)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.doWrite(NioEndpoint.java:1276)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.doWrite(SocketWrapperBase.java:670)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.flushBlocking(SocketWrapperBase.java:607)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]    at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase.flush(SocketWrapperBase.java:597)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]    at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer$SocketOutputBuffer.flush(Http11OutputBuffer.java:646)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]    at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.filters.ChunkedOutputFilter.flush(ChunkedOutputFilter.java:169)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]    at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11OutputBuffer.flush(Http11OutputBuffer.java:252)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]    at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.flush(Http11Processor.java:1564)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]    at
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessor.action(AbstractProcessor.java:352)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]    at
>   org.apache.coyote.Response.action(Response.java:173)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.doFlush(OutputBuffer.java:317)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.flush(OutputBuffer.java:284)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]    at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.flush(CoyoteOutputStream.java:118)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]    at
>   sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:297)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_151]   at
>   sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
>     at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_151]   at
>   org.springframework.util.StreamUtils.copy(StreamUtils.java:121)
>   ~[spring-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(StringHttpMessageConverter.java:103)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(StringHttpMessageConverter.java:43)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:224)
>   ~[spring-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseBodyEmitterReturnValueHandler$HttpMessageConvertingHandler.sendInternal(ResponseBodyEmitterReturnValueHandler.java:199)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseBodyEmitterReturnValueHandler$HttpMessageConvertingHandler.send(ResponseBodyEmitterReturnValueHandler.java:189)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseBodyEmitter.sendInternal(ResponseBodyEmitter.java:189)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseBodyEmitter.send(ResponseBodyEmitter.java:183)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.SseEmitter.send(SseEmitter.java:133)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ReactiveTypeHandler$SseEmitterSubscriber.send(ReactiveTypeHandler.java:341)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ReactiveTypeHandler$AbstractEmitterSubscriber.run(ReactiveTypeHandler.java:283)
>   ~[spring-webmvc-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]  at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_151]

Comment: can u post ur project on github? a minimal, verifiable sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More details to joshiste's answer.

Change dependency version to 2.0.1-SNAPSHOT:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>de.codecentric</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-admin-starter-server</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Add repository element:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>sonatype-nexus-snapshots</id>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>                        
        <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Answer (score 3):

The 2.0.0 doesn't include the cloud features. Please use 2.0.1 (currently only snpashots available)

Comment: I've confirmed the 2.0.1 release version fixed this issue